# How to find the amount of objects that a user has on a particular date?

Tags: mongodb

I am learning Mongo and I am trying to provide two metrics for a given user in given time range. Precisely I need to calculate this kind of array of objects that represents state of the backpack for the particular day:

```
{ 
  data: [
    { date: '2020-01-01', itemsCount: 1, itemsSize: 5 },
    { date: '2020-01-02', itemsCount: 3, itemsSize: 12 },
    ...

  ]
}
```

where `itemsCount` is the total number of all user items and `itemsSize` is the sum of sizes of all items.

I have a mongodb collection of four types of events with the structure as below:

```
{
  type: "backpack.created"    // type of event
  backpackId: 1,
  timestamp: 1604311699,      // timestamp in seconds when event occurred
  ownerId: 1,
  size: 15,                   // sum of sizes of all items located in the backpack
  itemsCount: 5               // number of items in the backpack                    
}
```

```
{
  type: "backpack.owner.changed",    
  timestamp: 1604311699, 
  newOwnerId: 2,
  backpackId: 1,                    
}
```

```
{
  type: "backpack.deleted",
  backpackId: 1,
  timestamp: 1604311699,               
}
```

```
{
  type: "backpack.updated",
  backpackId: 1,
  size: 5,
  itemsCount: 25,
  timestamp: 1604311699,                             
}
```

First idea to solve the problem was to load all the events for the given user and time range in memory and do calculations, but this sounds terrible memory-wise. So I am wondering how to do such a query that will provide me the given filtered metrics? And is it possible to do it with Mongo? I do not know how to handle ownership changes in this.

**Note**: backpack created and deleted same day means it's contribution for that day is 0.

Comment: Clarification: Get all events within a date range, bucket by 24 period, then "sum" the events of create + updated + deleted, ignoring owner changed?   So a backpack created and deleted same day means its contribution for that day is 0?   And what happened to the `timestamp` field on `backpack.updated`?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I have updated the original question. What do you mean by `bucket by 24 period`?

Comment: 24 hour period.   So the challenge is `updated` is like `created`; both specify a total amount.   `updated` does not have an *incremental* change; thus, using `$sum` in a simple way will not work.   Not the end of the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe what you wish to do, which is create a cross-backpack position by day, is *fully* served by a mongodb pipeline.  The reason is that you need to track state day over day so that when, say, 3 days from now a `backpack.deleted` event occurs, you know how much to delete from the running aggregate position.

That said, mongodb can help you in 2 ways:

1. Act as a master filter of events for a range and excluding `owner.changed` which does not affect position.
2. A convenient "last event" of the day generator.  Since update has new total levels, not incremental, the last update of the day *is* the new position; if the last event is delete, the position for that backpack becomes zero.

```js
var sdate = new ISODate("2020-11-01");
var edate = new ISODate("2020-12-01");

c=db.foo.aggregate([
    // Convert timestamp into something more filterable:                            
    {$addFields: {D: {$toDate: {$multiply:[1000,"$timestamp"]} } }}

    // Use DB to do what it does best: filter!                                      
    ,{$match: {type: {$ne: 'backpack.owner.changed'},
               D: {$gte: sdate, $lt: edate}
              }}

    // Ensure material is coming out date DESCENDING (most recent first)            
    // to properly set up for the $group/$first to follow:                          
    ,{$sort: {D:-1}}

    // Since the timestamps include hours/mins/seconds and we only                  
    // care about day, just turn it into string.  In mongodb 5.0,                   
    // you should use $dateTrunc to set H:H:S to 00:00:00.                          
    ,{$group: {_id: {
        D: {$dateToString: {format: '%Y-%m-%d', date:'$D'}},
        B: '$backpackId'
    }
           // Thanks to the $sort above, regardless of the $group set           
           // ordering of date + backpackId, taking the $first is the           
           // last one for that particular day:                                 
               , Lsize: {$first: '$size'}
               , LitemsCount: {$first: '$itemsCount'}
           , Laction: {$first: '$type'}
              }}

    // Now, group *again* to reorganize the content by date alone.                  
    // This makes it easy for the client to pick up a cursor of                     
    // dates which is the intent of the day-to-day position                         
    // building:                                                                    
    ,{$group: {_id: '$_id.D',
               X: {$push: {B:'$_id.B'
                           , Lsize: '$Lsize'
                           , LitemsCount: '$LitemsCount'
                           , Laction: '$Laction'}
                  }
              }}

    // ...and of course sort by date so the client can easily                       
    // walk forward on the cursor by date:                                          
    ,{$sort: {'_id':1}}
]);
```

At this point you end up with something like this (there are more events in this output than the OP from my tests):

```js
{
    "_id" : "2020-11-02",
    "X" : [
        {
            "B" : 3,
            "Lsize" : 3,
            "LitemsCount" : 35,
            "Laction" : "backpack.created"
        },
        {
            "B" : 2,
            "Lsize" : 13,
            "LitemsCount" : 9,
            "Laction" : "backpack.created"
        },
        {
            "B" : 1,
            "Lsize" : 8,
            "LitemsCount" : 28,
            "Laction" : "backpack.updated"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "2020-11-03",
    "X" : [
        {
            "B" : 2,
            "Lsize" : 7,
            "LitemsCount" : 11,
            "Laction" : "backpack.updated"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "2020-11-04",
    "X" : [
        {
            "B" : 1,
            "Lsize" : null,
            "LitemsCount" : null,
            "Laction" : "backpack.deleted"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "2020-11-05",
    "X" : [
        {
            "B" : 3,
            "Lsize" : null,
            "LitemsCount" : null,
            "Laction" : "backpack.deleted"
        }
    ]
}
```

It is left as an exercise to the reader to walk this cursor and for each date+backpackId, accumulate a sum of `size` and `itemsCount` by `backpackId`.  Any time a `deleted` event is hit, on that day the sum goes to zero.  To get `size` and `itemsCount` from *all* the backpacks, simply ask for all the sums on a given date.
Moving the agg logic out of MongoDB also makes it easier to represent date aggregates for which there is no material, e.g.:

```js
    { date: '2020-01-01', itemsCount: 1, itemsSize: 5 },
    { date: '2020-01-02', itemsCount: 0, itemsSize: 0 },
    { date: '2020-01-03', itemsCount: 0, itemsSize: 0 },
    { date: '2020-01-04', itemsCount: 6, itemsSize: 21},
    ...
```

Comment: Wow thank you I have not expected that it would be that simple!